# Crop video by FFMPEG is bad quality

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am using the FFMPEG extension to crop video in php but cropped video quality is not good.

Please check my parameters. My code is:

```
exec("ffmpeg -i $fullVideo -ss $starting_time -t $ending_time -r 24 $smallVideo");
```

Comment: What is the desired cropped video you want and what does the currently cropped video show?

Comment: You need to show the complete console output/log from the `ffmpeg` command so we can see what is actually occurring; otherwise we can only guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upgrade the version of ffmpeg in your server that may help you to resolve the issue. 
You can use following guideline to install the new version or upgrade the version.

sudo apt-get -y remove ffmpeg x264 libav-tools libvpx-dev libx264-dev

https://gist.github.com/xdamman/e4f713c8cd1a389a5917

Comment: Thanks Sir, Issue has been resolved , after updating the ffmpeg.

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually [cropping](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop), you're [seeking](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking).

Anyway, semantics aside, you're video is being re-encoded, where what you probably need is a direct stream copy...

```
exec("ffmpeg -i $fullVideo -ss $starting_time -t $ending_time -c copy $smallVideo");
```

Comment: I have still used these codes but on one crop good quality video.

Comment: //exec("ffmpeg -i $fullVideo -ss $full_video_starting -t $full_video_ending -r 24 $smallVideo"); 
//exec("ffmpeg -i $fullVideo -ss $full_video_starting -t $full_video_ending -codec copy $smallVideo"); 
//exec("ffmpeg -i $fullVideo -ss $full_video_starting -t $full_video_ending -r 24 $smallVideo1"); 
//exec("ffmpeg -i $fullVideo -metadata:s:v rotate='0' -vf 'hflip,vflip' -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -acodec copy $smallVideo1");

Comment: //exec("ffmpeg -i $fullVideo -b:v 64k -bufsize 64k $smallVideo1");
//exec("ffmpeg -i $fullVideo -filter:v 'crop=100:100:0:36' $smallVideo1");    
//exec("ffmpeg -i $fullVideo -vf 'transpose=1' $smallVideo1");    
exec("ffmpeg -i $fullVideo -ss $full_video_starting -t $full_video_ending scale=320:240  $smallVideo");
//exec("ffmpeg -i $fullVideo -ss $full_video_starting -t $full_video_ending 'crop=736:414:414:0' $smallVideo1");